# Migrating Yii2 from Apache to Nginx - failed on backend app

Tags: php, apache, nginx, yii2

I try to move my Yii2 app from using apache to nginx. I'm using Yii2 advanced template on a single domain, so I follow the solution from [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx/) creating a symlink from `frontend/web` to the `backend/web`. This solution works fine when I'm using apache, but when I try to use nginx I can't open the backend app.

The frontend app works fine, but when I try to open the backend app using `app.local/belakang`, it is redirected to `app.local/belakang/site/login`, but still stuck in the frontend app and therefore giving a `[yii\web\HttpException:404] exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "belakang/site/login".'`

Here is the symlinks that I have on the `frontend/web` directory :

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant   17 Jun 24 14:03 belakang -> ../../backend/web
```

and this is the nginx vhost config that I use:

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4

    server_name app.local;
    root        /var/www/html/frontend/web;
    index       index.php;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help so that I can open the backend app from `app.local/belakang` ?

Comment: I've made special subdomain for my yii2 advanced app for backend. I thinks it is better to have separate subdomain for admin instead of subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it myself by adding config below

```
location ^~ /belakang {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /belakang/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5-fpm.sock;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
```